# MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gunicorn

When I start some of my services, it reports such warnings and the services stop:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py:75: 
UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient with connect=False, 
or create client after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: 
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing>
"MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient "
```

However, the `MongoClient` has been using the parameter `connect=False`, as you can review the code below:

```py
client = MongoClient(host, port, connect=False)
```

It is still not working. By the way, I have upgraded my pymongo version to 3.4.0. 
Can someone give me some suggestions?

Cheers,
Kai

Answer (score 19):

If you *use* the MongoClient for any operation that contacts the MongoDB server, then the MongoClient must create connections and background threads. Once this has happened it is no longer safe to use it in a forked subprocess. For example, this is unsafe:

```
client = MongoClient(connect=False)
client.admin.command('ping')  # The client now connects.
if not os.fork():
    client.admin.command('ping')  # This will print the warning.
```

Make sure that you aren't doing anything with the client before the fork that causes it to connect.

Better yet, don't create the client before forking at all. Create your client after the fork, in the subprocess.

Comment: The code was working before I restarted all services. That is quite strange.

Comment: @KOPLee - same thing here. I think it has something to do with race conditions after the introduction of proper async in python and a slew of problems it led to.

Comment: Why is this unsafe?

Comment: It is OK to create the client before forking, but you must not perform any operation with it or connect to a database before forking. I wish I had found the above answer earlier...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with slightly different setup. For me it was Flask app and `MongoClient` was created via `flask_mongoengine`. Here is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139089/mongoclient-opened-before-fork-create-mongoclient-only-flask/56474420#56474420)

Answer (score 0):

I chose to do it like this:

```
import pymongo, os

from pymongo import MongoClient

_db = {}

# recupere la connexion
def getBdd():
    global _db
    if not os.getpid() in _db:
        client = MongoClient( URI )
        _db[ os.getpid() ] = client[ BDD ]
    return _db[ os.getpid() ]

# recupere une collection
def getCol( sCol ):
    return getBdd()[ sCol ]
```

By creating a dictionary compartmentalized by process identifier.