# MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only Flask

Tags: flask, pymongo, uwsgi, flask-mongoengine

I am running Flask with uwsgi threaded mode with processes 4 and using pymongo also flask_mongoengine and uwsgi says "MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only "
I tried connect with connect=False but the result is same

lazy-apps = true problem is fixed but it seems that uwsgi needs more time to load 
what can be done for best performance ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'DB': 'somedb', "USERNAME":
>   "dbadmin", "PASSWORD":"somepass",'connect': False}

And

> client = MongoClient(connect=False, username='dbadmin',
>   password='somepass', authSource='somedb')

Solutions for Mongoengine and For pymongo

Answer (score 6):

If you use [appllication factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/) then setting **MongoClient** `connection=False` should fix it. It worked for my flask app (v1.0.2), running behind [uwsgi server](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (v2.0.18).

### Example

```py
# __init__.py

from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

mongo = MongoEngine()

def create_app(config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    app.config['MONGODB_PORT'] = 27017
    app.config['MONGODB_DB'] = 'datazzilla'

    # NOTE: This fixes "UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork."
    # I'm not aware of side effects yet. Default value is/was "True"
    app.config['MONGODB_CONNECT'] = False

    mongo.init_app(app)

    return app
```

Comment: is it some different when I am using it with flask-login