# MongoEngine connects to incorrect database during testing

Tags: mongodb, flask, pytest, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

## Context

I'm creating `Flask` app connected to `mongodb` using [MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/) via [flask-mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/) extension. I create my app using `application factory pattern` as specified in [configuration](http://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/#configuration) instructions.

## Problem

While running test(s), I specified testing database named `datazilla_test` which is passed to `mongo` instance via `mongo.init_app(app)`. Even though my `app.config['MONGODB_DB']` and `mongo.app.config['MONGODB_DB']` instance has correct value (`datazilla_test`), this value is not reflected in `mongo` instance. Thus, when I run assertion `assert mongo.get_db().name == mongo.app.config['MONGODB_DB']` this error is triggered `AssertionError: assert 'datazzilla' == 'datazzilla_test'`

## Question

What am I doing wrong? Why database connection persist with default database `datazzilla` rather, than `datazilla_test`? How to fix it?

## Source Code

```py
# __init__.py
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

mongo = MongoEngine()


def create_app(config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    app.config['MONGODB_PORT'] = '27017'
    app.config['MONGODB_DB'] = 'datazzilla'

    # override default config
    if config is not None:
        app.config.from_mapping(config)

    mongo.init_app(app)

    return app
```

```py
# conftest.py
import pytest
from app import mongo
from app import create_app


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app({
        'MONGODB_DB': 'datazzilla_test',
    })

    assert mongo.get_db().name == mongo.app.config['MONGODB_DB']
    # AssertionError: assert 'datazzilla' == 'datazzilla_test'

    return app
```

Comment: It sounds like your global `mongo` instance is already connected to the "datazzilla" database before your fixture gets called. Could you call `mongo.get_db()` before the `create_app` call and let me know the outcome (if no other connection got made, it should raise a MongoEngineConnectionError)

Comment: I did what you suggested. The outcome of calling `mongo.get_db()` before `create_app` results with db connection pointed to `datazzilla` db.

Answer (score 3):

Mongoengine is already connected when your fixture is called, when you call `app = create_app` from your fixture, it tries to re-establish the connection but fails silently (as it sees that there is an existing default connection established).

This got reworked in the development version of mongoengine (see https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/pull/2038) but wasn't released yet (As of 04-JUN-2019). When that version gets out, you'll be able to disconnect any existing mongoengine connection by calling `disconnect_all`

In the meantime, you can either:
- check where the existing connection is created and prevent it
- try to disconnect the existing connection by using the following:

```
from mongoengine.connection import disconnect, _connection_settings

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    disconnect()
    del _connection_settings['default']
    app = create_app(...)
    ...
```

But it may have other side effects

Comment: Thanks, it worked! So far I cannot experience any side effects therfore, I'm up-voting this question :) I'm looking forward to see mongoengine  release > 0.17.0 and test `disconnect_all`. P.S. My mongoclient throws this warning `MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking.` By any chance are you aware of this behavior and know how to fix it ?

Comment: P.S.2 I found solution for `UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork.` I had to change connect property on mongo client from `true` (default) to `false`. e.g `MongoClient(connect=False)`

Comment: It sounds like you are forking the process after it established the Mongoengine connection

Answer (score -1):

### Context

Coincidentally, I figure-out fix for this problem. @bagerard answer is correct! It works for `MongoClient` where client's connect is set to `True` -this is/should be default value.

```
MongoClient(host=['mongo:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=False, read_preference=Primary())
```

If that is the case, then you have to `disconnect database and delete connection settings` as @bagerard explains.

### Solution

However, if you change `MongoClient` connection to `False`, then you **don't have to disconnect database and delete connection settings**. At the end solution that worked for me was this solution.

```py
def create_app(config=None):
    ...
    app.config['MONGODB_CONNECT'] = False
    ...
```

### Notes

As I wrote earlier. I found this solution coincidentally, I was trying to solve this problem [MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139089/mongoclient-opened-before-fork-create-mongoclient-only-flask/56474420). It turned out that it fixes both problems :)

P.S If there are any side effects I'm not aware of them at this point! If you find some then please share them in comments section.