# How to correctly use MongoDB client connections

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb

I'm building a simple test web application that stores info users enter in a mongo database.

No errors come up, but I always get the following warning (Im using django) when using the client.

```
/home/<User>/.local/share/virtualenvs/<Name>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py:155: UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe                                                       
  "MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only "
```

After checking out the API docs, it seems that the warning pops up when using `fork()` which im not explicitly using.

Maybe something that I'm doing is actually triggering the fork.

I create my mongo client at `__init__` and then import the variable to my mongoDB handler. Then, that client that I imported is used inserting or updating items in the DB.

What is the correct way of creating and then using a mongo client to prevent this warning from appearing?

Comment: Is this the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139089/mongoclient-opened-before-fork-create-mongoclient-only-flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the link Joe provided, ensure you are not performing database operations in global scope which is the most common way I can think of to get a client instantiated prior to a fork.

You are probably using a web server that forks under the hood, or some sort of reloader for development that forks to reset state.